# Query to check if record exists and also column value in table is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a value for `@InvId` which identifies a `Contact` record which can then be joined to a `UserAccount` record e.g.

```
select *
from UserAccount UA
join Contact as c on UA.email = C.email and C.type = 'Director'
where C.InvId = @InvId
```

I am working on 2 scenarios where I need to set a flag variable `@userExits` if

1. a matching record exists in the `Users` table and the `user_id` value is NULL in the `UserAccount` record.
2. a matching record does not exist in the `Users` table

The query I worked out so far is failing for second scenario.

```
declare @userExits int

if exists (
    select 1
    from UserAccount UA
    join Contact as c on UA.email = C.email and C.type = 'Director'
    where C.InvId = @InvId
    and exists (
        select 1
        from Users U
        where U.email = UA.email 
        and UA.user_id is null
    )
)
set @userExists = 1
```

Users table:

```
 user_id | first_name | last_name | email           | telephone
---------------------------------------------------------------
 10      | John       |  Doe      | jdoe@gmail.com  | 123456
 11      | Joe        |  Dane     | jdane@gmail.com | 3456789
```

Contact Table:

```
 contact_id | inv_id | first_name | last_name | email          | type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          | 100    | john       | Doe       | jdoe@gmail.com | director
```

UserAccount table:

```
 s_id | first_name | last_name | email           | username        | user_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    | john       | Doe       | jdoe@gmail.com  | jdoe@gmail.com  | 10
 2    | joe        | Dane      | jdane@gmail.com | jdane@gmail.com | null
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: If you could add some sample data which demonstrates test 2 that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your clarifications in the comments I *think* you want to test for the following 2 conditions:

Condition 1: `User` record exists but `user_id` is null

```
select 1
from UserAccount UA
inner join Contact as C on UA.email = C.email and C.[type] = 'Director'
where C.InvId = @InvId
-- User Record exists
and exists (select 1 from Users U where U.email = UA.email)
-- user_id is null
and UA.[user_id] is null
```

Condition 2: `User` record doesn't exist

```
select 1
from UserAccount UA
inner join Contact as C on UA.email = C.email and C.[type] = 'Director'
where C.InvId = @InvId
-- User Record doesn't exist
and not exists (select 1 from Users U where U.email = UA.email)
```

These can be combined with an `OR` to test both conditions as follows:

```
declare @userExists int;

if exists (
  select 1
  from UserAccount UA
  inner join Contact as C on UA.email = C.email and C.[type] = 'Director'
  where C.InvId = @InvId
  and (
    (UA.[user_id] is null and exists (select 1 from Users U where U.email = UA.email))
    or not exists (select 1 from Users U where U.email = UA.email)
  )
)
begin
  set @userExists = 1;
end;
```

As an aside should the variable really be called `@userExists`? Isn't it `@userNotExists`?

Note 1: It would be worth knowing what you then use the variable `@userExists` for - for example if you use it to update a record then most likely the update and test can be combined into a single statement.

Note 2: I have to assume this is only for test purposes? Because joining on email address isn't a recommended practise - unless you are prepared to put a unique constraint on email address, but some people still do share an email address.

Note 3: Its best practice to be consistent in your table naming as to whether you use the singular or plural form. You've used `Users` (plural) and `Contact` (singular).